# how to bind datagridview in ado.net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

i want to bind datagridview on form load using ado.net "Child list for field Physio_cureTable cannot be created". error iam paste here my code please give me suggestions or help

con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PhysioCure; Integrated Security=true");

```
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select RegisterNo,RegistrationDate,Stimulation,PationName,DateOfBirth,ContactNo,Occupation,Age,Sex,Weight,Chief_Complain,Investigation_Result,PastHistoryAny,Physical_Examination,Ref_By_Doctor,Medications,Prognosis,Electro_Therapy,Neuro_Rehabilitation,Ortho_Rehabilitation,Cardio_Pulmonery_Rehabilitation,Sports_Rehabilitation from Physio_cureTable where Syncoperation <>'D'",con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Physio_cureTable".ToString();// error coming this line
```

Comment: Can you elaborate you problem

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Physio_cureTable".ToString();
```

Physio_cureTable has to be a column name you have binded with the DataGridView

```
dataGridView1.DataMember = "RegisterNO".ToString();
```